# Vuex - Github - "vue-cli-service" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: github, vuex, vue2

Soy nueva en ésto y es la primera vez que subo un proyecto a GITHUB.

Estoy intentando subir un proyecto hecho con VUE2 + VUEX a Github.
Subo el código correctamente.
Cuando descargo el código que subí e intento arrancarlo con npm run serve, salta el siguiente error:

`"vue-cli-service" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo`

Éstos son los pasos que he llevado a cabo a través de la consola de comandos:

1. `git add .`
2. `git remote add origin https://github.com/usuario/nombre-repositorio`
3. `git commit -m "Primer commit"`
4. `git push -u origin main`

No sé si es que falta algún archivo o qué cosa. Investigando he visto que hay gente que en algún punto implementa ésto. Pero no sé exactamente en qué momento dar este comando
`npm -i g @vue/cli` , no si tendrá algo que ver.

Tambien he probado creando estos dos archivos: deploy.sh y vue.config.js.
He probado de mil maneras, pero si no me falla por un lado me falla por otro, y practicamente de cada vídeo que he visto o web que he leído, lo hacen de formas distintas.

Comment: Es por qué tienes que reinstalar todas las dependencias con `npm i` y después ejecutar `npm run serve`. De lo contrario te dará ese error

Comment: Si, era eso, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer para subir un repositorio a github es iniciarlo en la carpeta del proyecto que deseas subir:

```
   git init
```

Posteriormente realizar los pasos como bien indicas

```
  git add *

 git remote add origin https://github.com/usuario/nombre-repositorio

 git commit -m "Primer commit"

 git push -u origin main
```

Si no funciona con lo que te acabo de indicar , es debido a un problema con las dependencias :

Reinstalar todas las dependencias con

```
  npm i
```

y después ejecuta

```
 npm run serve
```

Espero que mi respuesta te haya ayudado

Answer (score 0):

**A los que no les funcione la respuesta correcta también pueden:**
Borrar la carpeta **node_mudules** y ejecutar los comandos
`npm i`
`npm run serve`

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero si te fijas bien @JorgeCarrera también indica reinstalar todas las dependencias como posible solución. ;)